# How much water is the atmosphere receiving

Tags: atmosphere, hydrology, water, water-vapour

I was reading this [Question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9488/how-much-water-is-the-atmosphere-losing-to-space) earlier about how if water is getting lost into space and one of the answers said that (paraphrase) the Earth lost about enough water for the oceans to reduce by 12 cm, if the Earth lost that amount of water, could it make up for the loss by receiving Water from Space? I did research about this
[Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20did%20earth%20get%20its%20water&rlz=1CASFJY_enUS1020&oq=how%20did%20Earth%20get%20its%20water&aqs=chrome.0.0i512l2j0i390.6038j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on)

> Far from the Sun, where temperatures are low, water formed icy objects such as comets, while closer to the Sun water reacted with rocky materials to form hydrated minerals. It's thought that the mostly likely way that planet Earth inherited its water was from asteroids and comets crashing into it.

Is the Earth still receiving Water this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[About 30,000 tonnes](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-021-01487-w) of extraterrestrial material arrives on earth every year, mostly in the form of submillimeter dust. Unfortunately, these [micrometeorites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micrometeorite) are pretty dry.  The wettest meteors [might be 10% water](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-021-01487-w) by weight, but a [generous estimate](https://books.google.ca/books?id=lDbMELpF8EcC&pg=PA78) of the average amount of water in micrometeorites would be 4%, so the earth is probably not receiving more than about a 1000 tonnes of water per year, and likely less.

The earth loses about [10,000 tonnes of water annually](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9488/how-much-water-is-the-atmosphere-losing-to-space), far more than it receives from space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now I can subtract the amount of water the Earth is losing by the amount its earning meaning it probably loses about 9000 Tonnes each year, Thank you.